# custom google form submit to "something went wrong"

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms, google-workspace

I have made a custom google form (html & css) and added its form action link, name="entry.*numbers*", and type="submit" on the button, however when I try to submit, it says 'something went wrong'. How should I resolve this?
FYI, I am using google app script of the google form, to run the custom html google form.

On Form submit
[image]

Answer (score 0):

managed to find a solution for my problem, somehow the date field from google form does not work, so use short answer for date field instead.